# How to access individul elements of a blob in dynamoDb using a hive script?

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb, hiveql, amazon-data-pipeline

I am transferring data from DynamoDB to S3 using a hive script in AWS Data Pipeline. I am using a script like this :

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_table ( PROPERTIES STRING, EMAIL
>   STRING, .............    ) STORED BY
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES
>   ("dynamodb.table.name" = "${DYNAMODB_INPUT_TABLE}",
>   "dynamodb.column.mapping" =
>   "PROPERTIES:Properties,EMAIL:EmailId...."); 
>   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_table (
>                   PROPERTIES STRING,
>                   EMAIL STRING,
>                                       ......
>                   )
>
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY'\n'
>
> LOCATION '${S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET}';
>
> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table SELECT * FROM dynamodb_table;

The Properties column in DyanmoDB table is like this

> Properties : String
>   :{\"deal\":null,\"MinType\":null,\"discount\":null}

that is it contains multiple attributes in it. I want each attribute in Properties to come as a separate column (not just a string in a single column). I want the output in this schema

deal      MinType        discount      EMAIL

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Properties column in proper JSON format?  If so, it looks like you can - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object